# Why can I not cast to [PSSession] declaring function parameters?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, type-accelerators

I cannot figure out how to cast a PSSession correctly for use as a parameter in a function.

Do I have to load an assembly or something?  I'm using Powershell v4.

I like to cast my functions parameters to make sure of correct usage.  What I'm trying is:

```
function Some-Remote-Task([PSSession] $Session, [String]$Target) {
  # Do stuff...
}
```

But I get this error while casting my Parameter:

```
Unable to find type [PSSession]. Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded.
```

Also, using `$mySession.GetType()` on a valid session yields the following:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                           
True     False    PSSession                                System.Object
```

So it seems like that should be the right type name...

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

I can now use `[PSSession]` properly.

By combining information from the link in biantist's comment: [Type Accelerator](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/07/09/simplify-your-script-by-creating-powershell-type-accelerators/)

With another answer here: [Simplify Your Script...](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Add-Type-Accelerators-to-b59908eb)

I added the **Type Accelerator** properly:

```
PS c:\> [PowerShell].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")::add(“PSSession”,”System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession”)

PS c:\> [PSSession]

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSSession                                System.Object
```

---

WAS:

In the end I used an alias.  Posted for others who also prefer a clean look.

```
New-Alias PSSession System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession
```

`-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` Is useful to add to it during testing if you keep rerunning the same code segments.

Comment: Personally, I would discourage this. I'm not even really sure how this worked in your code, as aliases are for commands/functions/cmdlets. What you're looking for is a [Type Accelerator](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/07/09/simplify-your-script-by-creating-powershell-type-accelerators/).

Comment: Above comment was before edit.  Type Accelerator now implemented.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
function Some-Remote-Task([System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession]$Session, [String]$Target) {
  # Do stuff...
}
```

Comment: This works.  I'm not accepting yet because I don't know if it's the best possible answer.

Comment: @Grallen 1) you can always accept and change that later. 2) This is the right answer. There is no context that I'm aware of where you can use `[PSSession]` alone like that. Check `$mySession.GetType().FullName`. This is the concatenation of `$mySession.GetType().Namespace` and `$mySession.GetType().Name`.